# "Error. EPERM: operation not permitted, stat" Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node.js-fs

I'm getting the below error when getting files from the path on the client's machine:

[image]

I've function in my electron main process in which all the files are read from the path and uploaded to the server. Then once uploaded it is deleted from the machine.

Below is my code:

```
const stats = fs.statSync(path.join(app.getPath('appData'), 'Zinniax ChatHub/screenshots/') + fileName);
  const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
```

I'm getting an error at the `fs.statSync` function. I checked the permission of the folder as well as the individual file but all seems correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `EPERM: operation not permitted` almost always means a security permission issue. If windows, then maybe "Run as Administrator". If Linux, then maybe "chmod 777" or "sudo" would work.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin I checked the folder and file permission but they are all ok

Comment: Does opening up your program using `Run as Administrator` help? It's possible that, e.g. `ZinniaX Chathub` or something was installed using admin, and therefore to run it you'd need admin. I'd therefore try opening the program using `Run as Administrator` to test it, even if the project folder itself is correct.

Comment: (That, or, if you're connecting to a remote machine, make sure their FTP username/password/IPADDRESS/PORT is correct.)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin clients do not have admin access. Their IT admins intall on over more than 300 machines with RMM software.

Answer (score -1):

Change mod permissions on your images.

```
$ chmod 777 <image file name>
```

You can do this either file and both the directory.

Comment: The screenshot they posted is for windows so you would need to use the `icacls` command for windows (likely as administrator) to adjust the permissions on whatever temporary directories it is writing to.

Comment: As mentioned, the permission is all enabled for the current user to the folder as well as the files.